# Oracle Regexp_replace string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

Let's say I have the following string:

> ```
> notNull(devhx_8_other2_name_2)  AND   notNull(devhx_8_other2_amt)
> ```

How can I use `regexp_replace` to change it to:

> ```
> (devhx_8_other2_name_2) is not null AND (devhx_8_other2_amt) is not null
> ```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, how many constraint can you have in your string? Always 2? Can you even handle OR or only AND?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
regexp_replace(col, 'notNull(\([^)]+\))', '\1 is not null', 1, 0)
```

This looks for 'notNull' followed immediately by an opening parenthesis, other characters and a closing parenthesis. It replaces this with the string including the parentheses, but without 'notNull' and appends 'is not null'.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Sometimes the string says 'notNull' and sometimes it says 'isNull'.

So I went with this:
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col, 'notNull(\([^)]+\))', '\1 is not null', 1, 0),  'isNull(\([^)]+\))', '\1 is null', 1, 0)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pattern:

- `notNull` - match the string
- `(` - start a capture group
- `\(.+?\)` - match an opening bracket then one-or-more characters but as few as possible until it matches a closing bracket
- `)` - end of the capture group.

And then replace it with `\1 is not null` which will substitute `\1` for the value matched in the first capture group. Like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         your_column,
         'notNull(\(.+?\))',
         '\1 is not null'
       )
FROM   your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your strings are always in the format you showed, you don't need regular expressions:

```
replace( replace( yourString, ')', ') is not null '), 'notNull', '')
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following regexp_replace function:

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(string_name,"notNull",""),"')","') is not null")
```

Here I replace the 'notNull' with a non space i.e. '' and then replace the closing bracket i.e. ')' with a closing bracket, a space and the text 'is not null'.

Comment: You need to escape the '(' in the external replace

Comment: String literals are surrounded by single quotes - In oracle, double quotes are used to enforce case-sensitivity in names for columns/tables/other database objects. Also, the escape character in regular expressions is \ not `'`.